# Using lapply to nested list

Tags: r

I have a next structure data frame qw[[i]], i = 19 (nested list). For example:

```r
dput(qw[[19]])
list(c(87.6755555555556, 36, 117.277222222222, 64.7858333333333
), c(46.44, 19.4966666666667, 207.101666666667, 92.5783333333333)
...
```

And I don't know how to use lapply (X, FUN = norm), that calculate norm for each block:

```
list(c(87.6755555555556, 36, 117.277222222222, 64.7858333333333)
```

```r
qnw <- lapply(matrix(unlist(qw)), FUN = norm)
```

after I get the same error:

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 'A' must be a numeric matrix
```

How fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like a nested `list` of `vector`s.  We may use recursive apply (`rapply`)

```
rapply(qw, f = \(x) norm(matrix(x)))
```

---

Or use a nested `sapply/lapply`

```
as.vector(sapply(qw, \(x) sapply(x, \(y) norm(matrix(y)))))
```